# How to force the browser to cache a page .html?

Tags: javascript, html, file, caching

Someone know how to force a page cache in the browser? I need to reload a page several times, and the browser isn't caching the page!

Comment: How do you know it is not caching the page?

Comment: where have you looked and what have you tried?

Comment: Depends on your browser, I would think (as this is a browser-specific question). What browser are you using?

Comment: Why are you wanting it cached if you need to reload it? Reloading is for getting new data, while caching is for when you don't want it to update the page...

Comment: Thanks to everybody! I'm sorry to leave them waiting!... I'm developing for SmartTV, and the app run in the EngineApp 3.0 Browser... I don't know what is this browser, but run with webkit... I will study more about it!...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If** browser is not caching the page there's no much you can do than using one of them:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

OR

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="private">
```

You **can't** programatically override browser settings. It would be a security issue!

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">` there are other factors to consider.

Note that some browsers have a file size limit for caching ... keep html below 25Kb if you can and external resources like css, js etc... below 1Mb, but for browser specifics see: [here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/) and [here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/07/12/mobile-browser-cache-limits-revisited/)

You can check `browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size` on some browsers and you can approximate the length with `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML.length` if it is not possible to precalculate the sizes of your files.

Your server needs to appropriately set "Last-Modified" and "Expires"

This will only increase the likelihood of caching if it is enabled though, not force it.  You might consider using local storage if it is enabled and caching is not (some people will just disable caching altogether to cope with 1 particular site)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this metatag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

Comment: "The Meta HTTP-EQUIV CACHE-CONTROL is [specifically] used by Internet Explorer." http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv_cache_control just FYI

Comment: @Bucky24 That is not borne out by others, e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_meta_httpequiv.asp